# Is there a way to name Series based on data of point in LightningChart JS?

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

Currently I am hardcoding the value of series as shown below

```
   // Create a new series using the previously created axis for X axis
     let chartSeries = this.chart.addPointSeries({ pointShape: PointShape.Circle, xAxis: createdAxis })
        .setName(' operation')
        .setPointFillStyle(seriesColor)
        .setPointSize(5)
```

But I would like to get Series name from data for the point

Comment: The question is unclear for me. Could you provide a bit more context. Like what  is the format you get your data and how the name should be got from the data. Should the name be some specific field from your data? Or would you like to have some field tied to each data point so that you can show it in the data cursor?

Comment: Would like to have a  field tied to each data point so as to show it in the data cursor